# convert the original structure to the transformed data structure as below

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

can anyone help me in writing sql query in oracel or in sql server transforming the following image structure from original to transformed structure.

[image: 1ddd]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Indicator = 1 THEN Color ELSE NULL END) AS Color,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Indicator = 2 THEN Shape ELSE NULL END) AS Shape,
       SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```